# Connecting to remote mySql database manually

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I want to know how to connect to a MySql database in a remote server from windows 7 .I want to give an external connection from Administrative panel.How to give connection to the database ? I have a php coding to insert and retrieve values from the remote database .But before that i need to connect to the remote database manually ? Pls can you help me out with this .#

```
    <?PHP 
         $user_name = "fbapp"; 
         $password = " 123";
         $database = "fb_db";
         $server = "mysql.dfw1.stabletransit.com";

           $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
           $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

       if ($db_found) {

      $SQL = "INSERT INTO Sample(Firstname, Lastnamme)
      VALUES (35,67)");

       $result = mysql_query($SQL);

       mysql_close($db_handle);

       echo "Records added to the database";

      }
     else {

     echo "Database NOT Found ";
     mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Use Putty or Similar SSH client to login to the remote Machine and then Use Mysql ?

Comment: am working with windows ..how could do that ?

Comment: Download Putty: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply create a mysql user and allow the same from your host to connect. So create user at 
   example1.com MYSQL and allow your new user to connect from your example2.com.
2. Then allow a firewall rule on mysql port from that very host

Comment: sorry i cant get you ..I have already mysql database in my remote server ..i just want to give a connection to t

Comment: @user1957553 Mysql also has "host permissions". In your remote mysql database allow your user "t" to connect from outside. Then simply connect to it like usual and give the ip address of your remote database under "host"

Comment: connect to it like usual ?do you mean with from Administrative tools ?

Comment: i have added the code ..do you want to give my host name in $server or ip address ? but other than from coding do you require any manual connection to the remote database ? as we do it from our control panel ->administrative tools?

Comment: @user1957553 you can either give host name or ip address, any will do. And no, no other connection is required

Comment: but that coding above is correct ?? when i run the query select * from table no row is returned ..I cant find out what is the problem ?

Comment: what is the result of db connection? does it return false?

Comment: no am returning nothng.. i run my coding using Notepad++ and i checked my database .but when i query no row is retured

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt

```
    mysql -u user_name -ppassword -h ip-adress
```

use ip-adress of machine where mysql is running

Comment: hi here am getting an error : mysql is not recogzined as external or internal command operable program or batch file

Comment: supose that mysql is installed in c:\mysql
type:

c:\mysql\bin\mysql -u root [-p]

also, in your
c:\mysql\bin\ folder you will find winmysqladmin.exe utility, try running it and install mysql as a service...

Comment: ya i got it .But my database is stored in the server .I have a username and password to access it .Wt should i do now?

Comment: please Install Mysql on your machine. This is the only way to access throgh dos prompt. else you can use putty software to access remote mysql using above command.

Comment: if i have mysql on my machine ..then how can i connect the mysql in my server ??

Comment: Its just for recognizing command by windows machine using parameter -h will determine location i.e machine IP address.